# select tag is keeping initial state value and not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm having some issues updating a select tag value. When I click on it and try changing the value it logs the new value to the console, but it's value is not changing no matter how many times I click a different option. But when I make some changes in the code editor and save it it display the new value but if I try againg changing the value clicking on it it does not change.

```
const quantityChange = (e) => {
        console.log('changing quantity')
        const newCart = shoppingCart
        console.log(
            "new cart variable created. It's value is " + JSON.stringify(newCart)
        )
        const index = e.target.dataset.index
        console.log('Item index is ' + index)
        newCart[index]['quantity'] = e.target.value
        console.log(
            'The new quantity for the item is ' + newCart[index]['quantity']
        )
        setShoppingCart(newCart)
        console.log(
            'new value set for shopping cart. ' +
                JSON.stringify(shoppingCart)
        )
}

const ShoppingCart = ({ shoppingCart, quantityChange, removeFromCart }) => {
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    if (shoppingCart.length === 0) {
        return <div>There's no items in the shopping cart</div>
    }

    const options = []

    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        options.push(
            <option name="quantity-1" value={i} key={'qsfkajlf' + i}>
                {i}
            </option>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                There's {shoppingCart.length} item{shoppingCart.length > 1 && 's'} in
                your shopping cart.
            </h1>
            {shoppingCart.map((item, index) => {
                const { id, name, price, image, quantity } = item
                return (
                    <div key={id}>
                        <div className="flex-container">
                            <div className="img-container">
                                <img src={image} alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="item-info">
                                <h2>{name}</h2>
                                <p>${price}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="remove-quantity">
                                <div className="quantity">
                                    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                                        {/* TODO: don't allow more than 10 items */}
                                        <select
                                            id="quantity"
                                            data-index={index}
                                            onChange={quantityChange}
                                            value={quantity}
                                        >
                                            {options}
                                        </select>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div className="remove-container">
                                    <button data-remove={index} onClick={removeFromCart}>
                                        x
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where is your useState hook and why is the event handler outside of the function?

Comment: It is on the app.js file. The event handler was outside the file because I thought that maybethe reason why it wasn't working was because it wasn't on the app.js file. My problem is fixed now though thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't updating because you are doing this:

```
const quantityChange = (e) => {
        console.log('changing quantity')
        const newCart = shoppingCart // <-- copy a reference to shoppingCart
        
        // do stuff

        setShoppingCart(newCart) // <-- write the original (modified) object back in
        
}
```

As the object reference doesn't change, the re-render isn't triggered.

Instead, you just need to copy your object (instead of just copying the reference):

```
 const quantityChange = (e) => {
        console.log('changing quantity')
        const newCart = {...shoppingCart} // <-- copy the contents into a new object
```